# Get parameter from config.yml in entity class without relying on controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have to get a config file parameter in entity class event callback. I don't want to rely on rhz controller because I need this functionality in fixtures class too etc, could somebody give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

If you need your callback to be aware of something from your configuration, I suggest you to create an event listener separated from your entity.

Once you have your event listener class, you can register a service for it into the DIC.
Finally, to register it into the doctrine entity manager, you simply add the `doctrine.event_listener` tag.